# SQL join to always return initial match and NULLs for subsequent mismatches

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

How can a join be created that will always return a row for those units in Unit that have a row in Test even when the row in test is in TestDetail with a PartID that has a row in Part with a PartFamilyID that has a row in PartFamily with a Name not equal to, in this case, B. In other words, always return a record for those units with a test record but with NULL values when the subsequent joins are false.

For example, from the code below I expected (I apologize I do not have the reputation to post images and I cannot figure out a way to post a table):

```
u.ID t.IDt.UnitID td.ID td.TestID td.PartID p.ID p.PartFamilyID pf.ID pf.Name

1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

2   15  2   114 15  1115    1115    11115   11115   E

3   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

4   14  4   113 14  1112    1112    11114   11114   D

4   16  4   115 16  1114    1114    11115   11115   E

5   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

---

```
declare @Results table (UnitID int, Value varchar(10))
insert into @Results (UnitID)
values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)

declare @Unit table (ID int)
insert into @Unit
values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)

declare @Test table (ID int, UnitID int)
insert into @Test
values (11,1),(12,1),(13,2),(14,4),(15,2),(16,4)

declare @TestDetail table (ID int, TestID int, PartID int)
insert into @TestDetail
values (111,11,1111),(112,13,1111),(113,14,1112),(114,15,1115),(115,16,1114)

declare @Part table (ID int, PartFamilyID int)
insert into @Part
values (1111,11112),(1112,11114),(1113,11114),(1114,11115),(1115,11115)

declare @PartFamily table (ID int, Name varchar(10))
insert into @PartFamily
values (11111,'A'),(11112,'B'),(11113,'C'),(11114,'D'),(11115,'E')

select *
from @Unit u
left join @Test t
on t.UnitID = u.ID
join @TestDetail td
on td.TestID = t.ID
join @Part p
on p.ID = td.PartID
join @PartFamily pf
on pf.ID = p.PartFamilyID
and pf.Name <> 'B'
```

However, the query excludes the rows where t.ID is NULL, so only the non-NULL t.ID rows for units 2 and 4 are left.

I have tried a variety of combinations of different types of joins without success.

Ultimately, I want to use the query to update a table:

```
update r
set r.Value = case when t.ID is not NULL then 'Yes' else 'No' end
from @Results r
left join @Unit u
on u.ID = r.UnitID
left join @Test t
on t.UnitID = u.ID
join @TestDetail td
on td.TestID = t.ID
join @Part p
on p.ID = td.PartID
join @PartFamily pf
on pf.ID = p.PartFamilyID
and pf.Name <> 'B'

select * from @Results
```

Which actually works when rows are returned.
If the NULL t.ID rows were returned, I expected the case statement to evaluate to Yes when at least one row for a single unit contained a non-NULL t.ID value.

I understand that I can subsequently update @Results where Value is NULL which is fine.

However, I am still trying to understand how to get the rows for all the units to be returned.
I thought that a left join would still leave the unit even when the subsequent (inner) joins return no matches.

If a unit has a match in Test but the test record has no match in TestDetail how can I get the record for the unit (with the NULL values in the columns of the subsequent tables without a match) returned?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you have to do left joins after the left join bec the way you do your update disables the left join of `t` since `t.ID=null` won't ever find a `TestDetail td`

```
select r.*
     , r.ValueNew = case when t.ID is not NULL then 'Yes' else 'No' end
from        @Results r
  left join @Unit u        on u.ID = r.UnitID
  left join @Test t        on t.UnitID = u.ID
  left join @TestDetail td on td.TestID = t.ID
  left join @Part p        on p.ID = td.PartID
  left join @PartFamily pf on pf.ID = p.PartFamilyID and pf.Name <> 'B'
```

this way, you will have your record r and nothing else